# How to map "settings" button to "recent apps" on Samsung Galaxy S4 with cyanogenmod

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, cyanogenmod, customization

On a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-M919 aka jfltetmo) running Cyanogenmod 11, how can I remap the leftmost hardware button so it brings up the recent apps list?

[image: photo of Samsung Galaxy S4 showing the hardware buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do.
Just go to `Settings->Buttons` and scroll down to `Menu button`. Below that you see `Short press action` and you can select your preferred action (*Recent apps switcher* in your case).

That's it. Depending on the developer of the ROM you may be able to remap other buttons as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable the s4 ithink s3 also , the BACK button for recent tabs buy touching it for 1-2 seconds ( in the accessibility setting)

that serves the same